# wait for all threads finishing one job then doing another

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

Suppose there are `NUM_TREADS` threads and they have to complete `job1()` before doing `job2()`. How to guarantee this to happen, like this:

```
void thread_func(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        job1();
        some_kind_of_waiting();
        job2();
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Will a semaphore like following work or are there any other/better solutions?

```
{
    static int done;
    static sem_t semaphore;

    if(__sync_fetch_and_add(&done, 1) == THREAD_NUMS-1) {
        done = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < THREAD_NUMS-1; i++)
            sem_post(&semaphore);
    } else
        sem_wait(&semaphore);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a c or a c++ question? The answer depends on the language you are using.

Comment: You are returning `NULL` from a `void` function.

Comment: Can you use C++ std::future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This precisely the problem that pthreads barriers are intended to solve.  Initialise the barrier with `NUM_THREADS` (in your main function, prior to spawning the threads):

```
pthread_barrier_t barrier;

pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, NUM_THREADS);
```

and use `pthread_barrier_wait()` to synchronise:

```
void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        job1();
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
        job2();
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

If you also need the threads to wait until all other threads have compelted `job2()` before any of them can start on `job1()` again, you can add a second wait on the barrier:

```
void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        job1();
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
        job2();
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: How would you reinitialize the barrier for subsequent loops?  Do you need a second barrier, or can you use the first barrier reinitialized, to make the threads wait after `job2()` completes and before resuming `job1()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The barrier does not need to be reinitialised.  Immediately after the threads are released from the barrier, the barrier is available for threads to wait on again.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You describe a high level concurrency control structure typically called by the name [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)). The C++ standard library has no implementation of barrier although it has been [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4204.html) and will hopefully be part of C++ standard library in the future.

Until the standard library provides a solution, you can of course implement the barrier yourself (you can use a condition variable), use a [platform specific threading API](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init) or a [wrapper library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers).